# Specifying the display of a django DateField from the model, and not form/input/settings?

Tags: python, django, templates, model, datefield

I have a Django model with a DateField, like so:

```
production_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I am trying to have that field display as the default Python date format in templates, which looks like "2000-01-01".  But in a Django template it displays as "Jan. 1, 2000."

In a Python shell, the date displays properly:

```
In [4]: resource.production_date                                                              
Out[4]: datetime.date(2014, 4, 20)

In [5]: str(resource.production_date)                                                         
Out[5]: '2014-04-20'
```

But in the template, when I call production_date, I get the other format.

I have many templates that use this value, and many ways the data gets added to the database.  So I do not want to go to each template and change the display.  I do not want to change the input form because that is not the only way data gets added.  I do not want to change my site settings.  I just want the field to display the default Python value.  How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd make a model method `get_production_date`.. So I'm not doing a crap ton of template tags, not a fan of them.. and then CTRL+Shift+F (only HTML files) find `production_date` and change them to `get_production_date`

#### models.py

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    production_date = models.DateField('Creation Time')
    # ..other fields

    def get_production_date(self)
        from datetime import datetime # idk if this is required, I assume so?
        return self.production_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

#### Template usage

```
{{ MyModelObj.get_production_date }}
```

---

#### Edit

I'm not 100% on what `accessor` are, but it sounds very **class base**y, which I don't use.
I doubt you can use a model method directly like that

**But!** for my admins, I use custom columns in my admin table like:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'calculated_total',)

    def calculated_total(self, obj):
        return obj.get_calculated_total()
```

..so like, there's gotta be something similar in class based views, right??
I've been googling, but I cannot find the correct words to describe it..

Comment: That's a good idea.  I wouldn't have to go change the display in all my templates, and the search replace wouldn't be that bad.  I wonder... does naming it get_production_date override the accessor?  That would be really nice. I'll play with it at work tomorrow..

Comment: I'm not sure what `accessor`s are, but I've added an edit with what I do in my admin to get the model methods to show in a column.. So hopefully you'll find that useful

Answer (score -1):

You can apply date filter in template

Example:

```
{{ birthday|date:"m, d, Y" }}
```

Django date format [reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#date)

Comment: I explicitly do not want format tags. That is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Now I get what you want, @Nealium solution will work as you want, good luck